# Setting multidimensional ArrayList and passing to another Activity

Tags: java, android, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have been trying to send this multidimensional ArrayList to another Activity for quite a while now, I have found many replies here on StackOverflow that seems related but unfortunately I could't apply any of those.

I think might be something wrong in the way that I'm setting the array.

```
ArrayList<java.io.Serializable> prodlist = new ArrayList<java.io.Serializable>();

for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainArr.length(); i++) {

    JSONObject childJSONObject = jsonMainArr.getJSONObject(i);
    String name      = childJSONObject.getString("Product");
    String reference = childJSONObject.getString("reference");
    String link      = childJSONObject.getString("img");
    String qty       = childJSONObject.getString("quantity");
    String prodbcode = childJSONObject.getString("bcode");

    ArrayList<java.io.Serializable> prod = new ArrayList<java.io.Serializable>();
    prod.add( prodbcode ); //0 barcode
    prod.add( name );      //1 name
    prod.add( reference ); //2 ref
    prod.add( link );      //3 img
    prod.add( qty );       //4 qty    

    prodlist.add(prod);

}
```

I'm not really sure if this `prodlist.add(prod)` is the right way to create this multidimensional array.

Than to pass the array I'm using:

```
 Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PrepareProduct.class);
 i.putExtra("products", prodlist);
 startActivity(i);
```

and to receive it on the other side:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
ArrayList productsNameList = extras.getParcelableArrayList("products");
```

But I'm getting an one dimension array instead of a 2D.

I'm a PHP developer trying to learn Java, and those arrays are struggling my head.
Thank you. I know that really likely what I need might already be here on StackOverflow but I really could not find it in a way I could apply.

Comment: what did you get in your one dimension array?

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to create a multidimensional ArrayList is by doing

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> prodlist = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
ArrayList<String> prod = new ArrayList<String>();
prod.add( prodbcode ); //0 barcode
prod.add( name );      //1 name
prod.add( reference ); //2 ref
prod.add( link );      //3 img
prod.add( qty );       //4 qty    

prodlist.add(prod);
```

The reason your code gave you a one dimensional ArrayList is because the prodlist ArrayList is of the type Serializable, and ArrayList itself implements Serializable so it compiles, but as prodlist is just one dimensional, that's what you get.

Comment: Ok... This language is so much more technical than PHP, hopefully i gonna get it. Thank you for your help, now I'm getting the array in the way I want to.